# converting a C function into Python3 form?

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

New in programming and need to find out what will be the following function in python3?

```
void expand (char s1 [], char s2[])
{
    char c;
    int i,j;
    i=j=0;
    while ((c=s1[i++]) != '\0')
        if (s1[i] =='-' && s1[i+1] >=c {
             i++;
             while (c<s1 [i])  
                 s2 [j++] = c++;
         }
         else
           s2 [j++] =c;
    s2 [j] = '\0';
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: I dont understand what does this function do...i know a bit of python but nothing of C

Comment: Some example input and expected output would be nice; it appears to alter a second string based on the characters in the first string but is a little.. opaque to read.

Comment: Looking at this C code makes me think: Python is beautiful.

Comment: And do you expect to use this with Python `bytes` or `str` objects? Is this to work with text or bytes?

Comment: I don't think this code compiles, since the line `if (s1[i] =='-' && s1[i+1] >=c {` is missing a right parenthesis. So I guess the equivalent Python code is `raise SyntaxError`.

Comment: One possible equivalent in Python might be `re.sub("(.)-(.)", lambda m: ''.join(chr(c) for c in range(ord(m.group(1)), ord(m.group(2))+1)), s1)`, which is to say that it may or may not do something similar but at least it preserves the crucial unreadability.

Comment: it should convert stings into stings, so i guess string objects...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The direct translation, working on `byte` objects only, would be:

```
def expand(s1):
    i = 0
    s2 = bytearray()
    while i < len(s1):
        c = s1[i]
        i += 1
        if (i + 1) < len(s1) and s1[i] == ord(b'-') and s1[i + 1] >= c:
            i += 1
            while c < s1[i]:
                s2.append(c)
                c += 1
        else:
           s2.append(c)
    return bytes(s2)
```

This appears to expand ranges in the form of `a-f` into `abcdef`:

```
>>> expand(b'a-f')
b'abcdef'
```

You can use regular expressions to do the same:

```
import re

_range = re.compile(rb'(.)-(.)')
def _range_expand(match):
    start, stop = match.group(1)[0], match.group(2)[0] + 1
    if start < stop:
        return bytes(range(start, stop))
    return match.group(0)

def expand(s1):
    return _range.sub(_range_expand, s1)
```

or, for unicode strings (type `str`) instead:

```
import re

_range = re.compile(r'(.)-(.)')
def _range_expand(match):
    start, stop = ord(match.group(1)), ord(match.group(2)) + 1
    if start < stop:
        return ''.join([chr(i) for i in range(start, stop)])
    return match.group(0)

def expand(s1):
    return _range.sub(_range_expand, s1)
```

Comment: how different would be if it workd with sting objects?

Comment: @Fatemeh: The C code would almost certainly work with byte characters, not Unicode.

Comment: @Fatemeh: But, I've added a string version for you anyway.

Comment: ok! this I understand better...dankije

Comment: @ Martijn: Already did

Comment: @Fatemeh: do read the link I included in my comment; there is a big green V next to the answer score (the up and down voting arrows); you can check that to indicate acceptance. :-)